# verb in English describing an action of putting a glowing-hot a piece of metal to a body to leave a mark

Tags: word-request

What's the verb in English describing an action of putting a glowing-hot a piece of metal to a body in order to leave a permanent undeletable mark on it? They did this to slave in America.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

brand (the act of marking something to identify it)

Comment: Thank you, but does it imply using a piece of hot metal to burn some part of body? If I say "Jack branded Sam yesterday", will it convey the message that one part of Sam's body is a burn done by Jack?

Comment: Yes.  "Jack branded Sam" says exactly that. The context of the action implies the use of hot metal. Historically hot metal was used to scar, or permanently burn an identifying mark into something. If it was not hot metal making a mark, additional information would be needed.

Comment: I see. Thank you.